# Karma unit test: angular typesafe spyon not works as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, angular-test

I have a generated (from openapi descriptor) cusomerService in angular with the following function:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

    public getCustomerInfoV2(requestCustomerIdRequest: RequestCustomerIdRequest, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<ResponseCustomerInfoV2>;
    public getCustomerInfoV2(requestCustomerIdRequest: RequestCustomerIdRequest, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<ResponseCustomerInfoV2>>;
    public getCustomerInfoV2(requestCustomerIdRequest: RequestCustomerIdRequest, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<ResponseCustomerInfoV2>>;
    public getCustomerInfoV2(requestCustomerIdRequest: RequestCustomerIdRequest, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {
    ...
```

when I want to mock the result in my spec.ts file, I would like to use a spyOn, but I get a compile error if I want to use it in a type-safe way:

```
spyOn(component.customerService, 'getCustomerInfoV2').and.returnValue(of({
      header: {
        requestId: '21212121',
        responseId: '212121',
        responseTimestamp: null,
        statusMessages: [],
        success: true,
      },
      payload: emptyCustomer,
    } as ResponseCustomerInfoV2));
```

Error message:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Observable<{ header: { requestId: string; responseId: string; responseTimestamp: any; statusMessages: any[]; success: boolean; }; payload: CustomerInfoV2; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<HttpEvent<ResponseCustomerInfoV2>>'.
  Type '{ header: { requestId: string; responseId: string; responseTimestamp: any; statusMessages: any[]; success: boolean; }; payload: CustomerInfoV2; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<ResponseCustomerInfoV2>'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type '{ header: { requestId: string; responseId: string; responseTimestamp: any; statusMessages: any[]; success: boolean; }; payload: CustomerInfoV2; }' but required in type 'HttpUserEvent<ResponseCustomerInfoV2>'.
```

I can remove the error message with the following unsafe code:

```
spyOn(component.customerService, 'getCustomerInfoV2').and.returnValue(of({
      header: {
        requestId: '21212121',
        responseId: '212121',
        responseTimestamp: null,
        statusMessages: [],
        success: true,
      },
      payload: emptyCustomer,
    } as ResponseCustomerInfoV2 as any));
```

Is there any way to use spyOn in a type-safe way?

Answer (score 0):

Your types aren't the same. In your spyOn, you have an Observable of ResponseCustomerInfoV2 but the safe type you're using is an Observable of an HttPEvent of type ResponseCustomerInfoV2.

Comment: The return value of spyOn is `Observable<ResponseCustomerInfoV2>` according to method declaration in CustomerService: `public getCustomerInfoV2(requestCustomerIdRequest: RequestCustomerIdRequest, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<ResponseCustomerInfoV2>;`

Comment: ```is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<ResponseCustomerInfoV2>'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type '{ header: { requestId: string; responseId: string; responseTimestamp: any; statusMessages: any[]; success: boolean; }; payload: CustomerInfoV2; }'```

Comment: this is the error message what I really cannot understand since the `Observable<HttpEvent<ResponseCustomerInfoV2>>` only the one of the return types. I don't use this overload of this method so I don't need to mock it.